# Is there a way to save window sizing information in wxWidgets 2.8+

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I know there is a way to save Window placement structures in Windows, but I'm wondering if there is an alternative way that can be used for cross platform wxWidgets app.

Also, what would be the best way to serialize this data without platform specific code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Window placement structures'?  Anything more than the location and size of the windows?

Comment: IIRC, there was something about multimonitor placement and auto adjustment for Windows. It's been a while. But basically, yes, only the size + maybe, position. In a OS native way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if all you want is to store the size and location of windows, then handle the window resize and move events so that they store this data in wxConfig.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.3/overview_config.html